# Rotation matrix appears to flatten model

Tags: java, android, matrix, opengl-es, rotation

So I have this problem with Open GL ES 2.0 in android where upon changing the rotation matrix it appears to stretch or flatten my model. I have searched many many times on bing and have yet to find an answer to this problem. I also noticed that some of my faces are not being drawn or are being drawn in the wrong order even though I double checked to makes sure that they are all in the right order and I found that they were.

Here is my .OBJ model loading code

```
ArrayList<float[]> vertexData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> indexData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<float[]> normalsData = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> normalsIndexData = new ArrayList<>();

        InputStream inputStream = manager.open(modelAddres);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        String args[];
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            args = line.split(" ");

            if(args[0].equals("v"))
            {
                //add new vertex
                float vertex[] = new float[COORDS_PER_VERTEX];

                vertex[0] = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);
                vertex[1] = Float.parseFloat(args[2]);
                vertex[2] = Float.parseFloat(args[3]);
                vertexData.add(vertex);
            }
            else if(args[0].equals("vn"))
            {
                //read new normal
                float normal[] = new float[3];

                normal[0] = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);
                normal[1] = Float.parseFloat(args[2]);
                normal[2] = Float.parseFloat(args[3]);

                normalsData.add(normal);
            }
            else if(args[0].equals("f"))
            {
                //get first face point
                String[] face = args[1].split("/");
                //read vertex
                int index = Integer.parseInt(face[0])-1;
                indexData.add(index);
                //read normal index data
                index = Integer.parseInt(face[2])-1;
                normalsIndexData.add(index);

                //get second face point
                face = args[2].split("/");
                //read vertex
                index = Integer.parseInt(face[0])-1;
                indexData.add(index);
                //read normal index data
                index = Integer.parseInt(face[2])-1;
                normalsIndexData.add(index);


                //get third face point
                face = args[3].split("/");
                //read vertex
                index = Integer.parseInt(face[0])-1;
                indexData.add(index);
                //read normal index data
                index = Integer.parseInt(face[2])-1;
                normalsIndexData.add(index);
            }
            else if(args[0].equals("texture"))
            {
                //store the ships texture name
                bitmapName = args[1];
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Float> verticies = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Float> normals = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Float> textures = new ArrayList<>();
        //finished parsing file so read in vetex data
        for(int i = 0;i < indexData.size();i++ )
        {
            int index = indexData.get(i);
            float[] vertex = vertexData.get(index);
            verticies.add(vertex[0]);
            verticies.add(vertex[1]);
            verticies.add(vertex[2]);
            //read normal
            index = normalsIndexData.get(i);
            float[] normal = normalsData.get(index);
            normals.add(normal[0]);
            normals.add(normal[1]);
            normals.add(normal[2]);
        }

        m_vertices = new float[verticies.size()];
        for(int i = 0;i < m_vertices.length;i++)
        {
            m_vertices[i] = verticies.get(i);
        }

        m_normals = new float[normals.size()];
        for(int i = 0;i < m_normals.length;i++)
        {
            m_normals[i] = normals.get(i);
        }
```

Here is my drawing code:

```
//Add program to openGL ES enviroment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(m_program);
    //multiply wvp;
    float[] MVP = new float[16];
    Matrix.multiplyMM(MVP,0,projection,0,view,0);
    float[] rotateMatrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.multiplyMM(MVP,0,MVP,0,modelMatrix,0);

    //get handle to vertex shaders vPosition member
    int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(m_program,"vPosition");


    //enable a handle to the models vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

    //Prepare the triangle
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, model.COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, model.COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4, model.getVertexBuffer()
    );

    int normalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(m_program,"aNormal");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, model.COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, model.COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4, model.getNormalsBuffer());

    //get the handle to the framet shaders color member
    int colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(m_program,"vColor");

    //set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    //get handle to shapes transfomr matrix
    int MVPHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(m_program,"uMVPMatrix");

    //pass the mvp matrix
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPHandle,1,false,MVP,0);

    int MHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(m_program,"uMMatrix");

    //pass the model matrix;
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MHandle,1,false,modelMatrix,0);

    int VHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(m_program,"uVMatrix");

    //pass the view matrix
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(VHandle,1,false,view,0);

    int PHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(m_program,"uPMatrix");

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(PHandle,1,false,projection,0);

    //GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);

    //Draw the model
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount());

    //Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
```

And here is my code that transforms my matrix

```
float[] translation = new float[16];
    float[] rotation = new float[16];
    float[] transformation = new float[16];
    //identify translation
    Matrix.setIdentityM(translation, 0);
    //translate translation
    Matrix.translateM(translation, 0, translation, 0, m_x, m_y, m_z);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(rotation, 0);

    //rotate rotation matrix
    Matrix.rotateM(rotation, 0, rotation,0, m_rotX, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(rotation,0,rotation,0,m_rotY,0,1,0);
    Matrix.rotateM(rotation,0,rotation,0,m_rotZ,0,0,1);

    //set transform matrix
   Matrix.setIdentityM(transformation,0);
    Matrix.scaleM(transformation, 0, transformation, 0, m_scaleX, m_scaleY, m_scaleZ);

    //update matrix
    Matrix.multiplyMM(m_matrix,0,translation,0,rotation,0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(m_matrix,0,m_matrix,0,transformation,0);
    m_needsGenerated = false;
```

And the shaders

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec4 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() 
{
 gl_FragColor = vColor*vNormal;
}

uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMMatrix;
uniform mat4 uVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 aNormal;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

varying vec4 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() {
 gl_Position = uPMatrix*uVMatrix*uMMatrix*vPosition;
 vNormal = aNormal;
 vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Edit: I am not the best at summarizing so if you need me to clarify my question or be more specific I can do that.

Comment: I have fixed the error that caused my model to not be drawn correctly, apparently it was as simple as enabling the depth buffer test using GLES20.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) which fixed the problem. I have left the original question on edited instead of removing the part about the model not drawing correctly so that this post could help those in the future with a similar problem. I am still having the weird streching and flattening effect upon rotating the rotate matrix so any further help with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finaly was able to fix it from what I could tell the rotation was messing up because I kept rotating the same matrix, after making so so it rotated 3 different rotation matricies and then multiplying them together it worked just fine. I fixed the error with it not rendering by simply enabling the depth buffer test.